# How to store JSON data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

JSON data

```
 {"level":{"Primary":"1","University":"3"},"sub":{"5":"literature","2":"bi","3":"maths"},"rate2":{"5":"20","6":"","7":"","9":"","2":"30","3":"50"},"name":"jessie","action":"test"}
```

I need to split data above and three tables.

1) tbl_user -columns(name)

2) tbl_user_level-columns(level,name)

3) tbl_subject_rate-columns(name,level,subject,rate)

Basically I need to do looping to store them.How do I access the JSON data and store them in mysql please?

I'm completely new to JSON, detailed explanation and help would be really appreciated..Thanks in advance.

EDITED:

I manage to see what the array looks like via var_dump($data) after decoding. It shows as below:

```
array (size=5)
  'level' => 
    array (size=2)
      'Primary' => string '1' (length=1)
      'University' => string '3' (length=1)
  'sub' => 
    array (size=3)
      5 => string 'literature' (length=10)
      2 => string 'bi' (length=2)
      3 => string 'maths' (length=5)
  'rate2' => 
    array (size=6)
      5 => string '20' (length=2)
      6 => string '' (length=0)
      7 => string '' (length=0)
      9 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '30' (length=2)
      3 => string '50' (length=2)
  'name' => string 'jessie' (length=6)
  'action' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

How to access, level, sub,rate2 and name handles' value?

Comment: Take the data out and organize it into three arrays. Then insert them using three queries. It's not rocket surgery.

Comment: @JohnConde, can you show how to access data from json?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @AaronKent, php mysql

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode` to convert your json into an array?

Comment: @AaronKent, yes like this: $data = json_decode($return, true);

Comment: Ok, then can you just explain what exactly isn't working? What have you tried? Some code would be useful to help guide you.

Comment: @AaronKent, I can't the value of data stored in JSON. I decoded into assosiative array.then try accessing a single variable like this:$data = json_decode($return, true);
$name=$data[0]["level"];

Comment: @AaronKent, it stores null value in the database for table user. How to achieve single and multiple values from JSOn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75973/discussion-between-aaron-kent-and-sweety).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = json_decode($return, true);

foreach($value['rate2'] as $v=>$k) {
  echo $v;
  echo $k;
}
```